# Pandas Column Multiindex Subtracting Columns from each other

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

**pandas DataFrame:**

Constructor:

```
c = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['AAPL','AMZN'],['price','custom']])
i = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01',end='2017-01-6')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=i,columns=c)

df1.loc[:,('AAPL','price')] = list(range(51,57))
df1.loc[:,('AMZN','price')] = list(range(101,107))
df1.loc[:,('AAPL','custom')] = list(range(1,7))
df1.loc[:,('AMZN','custom')] = list(range(17,23))
df1.index.set_names('Dates',inplace=True)
df1.sort_index(axis=1,level=0,inplace=True) # needed for pd.IndexSlice[]

df1
```

Produces: (can't figure out how to format the output from Jupyter Notebook)

```
    AAPL    AMZN
    custom  price   custom  price
Dates               
2017-01-01  1   51  17  101
2017-01-02  2   52  18  102
2017-01-03  3   53  19  103
2017-01-04  4   54  20  104
2017-01-05  5   55  21  105
2017-01-06  6   56  22  106
```

**Question:**
How can I create a 3rd column at the 2nd level of the MultiIndex that is the difference between `price` and `custom`? This should be calculated separately for each top column level, i.e. separately for AAPL and AMZN.

**Attempted Solutions:**

I tried using `pd.IndexSlice` in 2 ways, both give me all `NaNs`:

```
df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'price']].sub(df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'custom']])
df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'price']] - df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'custom']]
```

Returns:

```
    AAPL    AMZN
    custom  price   custom  price
Dates               
2017-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-03  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-04  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-05  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-06  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

How can I add a third column with the difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might consider subtraction of the values:

```
df1.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'price']] - df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'custom']].values
```

To join it back, you can use `pd.concat`:

```
In [221]: df2 = (df1.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'price']] - df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'custom']].values)\
                            .rename(columns={'price' : 'new'})

In [222]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[222]: 
             AAPL         AMZN       AAPL AMZN
           custom price custom price  new  new
Dates                                         
2017-01-01      1    51     17   101   50   84
2017-01-02      2    52     18   102   50   84
2017-01-03      3    53     19   103   50   84
2017-01-04      4    54     20   104   50   84
2017-01-05      5    55     21   105   50   84
2017-01-06      6    56     22   106   50   84
```

Comment: @JoshD No problem. Columns added to original here as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can subtract by values, then rename and last join to original:

```
a = df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'price']].sub(df1.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'custom']].values, 1)
       .rename(columns={'price':'sub'})
df1 = df1.join(a).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df1)
             AAPL             AMZN          
           custom price sub custom price sub
Dates                                       
2017-01-01      1    51  50     17   101  84
2017-01-02      2    52  50     18   102  84
2017-01-03      3    53  50     19   103  84
2017-01-04      4    54  50     20   104  84
2017-01-05      5    55  50     21   105  84
2017-01-06      6    56  50     22   106  84
```

Comment: Glad can help, columns are added to original ;)